# Rabbitmq Cluster configuration in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine

I have installed krew and installed rabbitmq-plugin using the same. Using the kubectl rabbitmq -n  create instance --image=custom-image:v1  command created a rabbitmq stateful set in my google kubernetes engine cluster.

The deployment was successful, but now when I try to update the stateful set with new image custom-image:v2, it is not getting rolled out.

Can someone help me here ?

Thanks & Regards,
Robin

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you check the statefulSet events you will get a hint on what's going on wrongly. Usually, if the previous version was running, v2 is not reachable or can't be deployed.

```
kubectl describe statefulset <statefulSet-name> -n <namespace>
```